# Duplicating section title problem in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, overleaf

[image: Backend table section title in table of contents seems to be duplicating]

When the section or one of its subsections is removed, the next subsection is the one that gets its title duplicated, here is the code for this part of the project:

```
\section{Backend design}
\subsection{Firebase authentication}

In the backend development chapter. The Auth-service.dart sign-up and sign-in, error 
handling and sign-out functionalities. AuthService().logout().

\subsection{Complete and edit profile backend}
\paragraph{}
After choosing to register for a new account on the app..

\subsection{Main.dart and global variables}
\paragraph{}
Every Flutter app starts by firstly executing code on the main.dart class...

\subsection{Firebase Firestore}
\paragraph{}
The Naffsi app uses a Firebase Firestore NoSQL database.executing tasks in a parallel 
manner independent of increased traffic \cite{firestoreSynchro}

\begin{figure}[H]
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=9.62cm]{Figures/Chapter5/snapshot.png}
     \caption{Firestore snapshot code example}
     \label{}
\end{figure}
```

some of the errors are:

```
Extra \fi.
Undefined control sequence.
Overfull \hbox (18.67542pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 600--601
```

These are relevant info to help reproduce

```
% TABLE OF CONTENTS, FIGURES AND TABLES
% ---------------------------

\newcommand{\thesisTOF}{
    \iftotalfigures
    \cleardoublepage
    \listoffigures
\fi
}

\newcommand{\thesisTOT}{
\iftotaltables
    \cleardoublepage
    \listoftables
\fi
}

\newcommand{\thesisTables}{
\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
{\setstretch{1.25}
    \tableofcontents
    \thesisTOF
    \thesisTOT
}

\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{1pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{15pt}
}

\RequirePackage{amsmath}
% --
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc} % font types and character 
 verification
\RequirePackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\RequirePackage[UKenglish]{isodate}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{longtable}
\RequirePackage{blindtext}
\RequirePackage{parskip}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\RequirePackage{layout}
\RequirePackage{courier}
\RequirePackage{subcaption}
\RequirePackage{url}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\RequirePackage[table,figure]{totalcount}
\RequirePackage{french}
\RequirePackage{appendix}
% -----------------
\RequirePackage{csquotes}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{datetime2}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{lmodern}
```

also

```
\usepackage{french}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Comment: The problem is due to packages or modifications not shown.  Please provide a complete Minimal Working Example.  Needless to say, duplicate titles should not cause duplicate numbers.

Comment: First of all, remove all those `\paragraph{}`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you, I added what I think is relevant, please tell me if I should add more

Comment: @egreg Alright, but what should I replace it with in order to keep desired indents

Comment: @Aminemessai If you want the indent after a sectional title, do `\usepackage{indentfirst}`.